# How to implement dual display in a Django app

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am developing a Django application for a school project and it is essentially one page that takes user input and another page that responds to the user input by displaying various alerts/data.

The end goal is to have the application launch on a tablet and display the user input page while having the summary data page displayed on the monitor. The issue is that as of now, these two are communicating via localStorage values. Obviously this will need to be changed down the line.

I am extremely new to Django and web dev so I was wondering if this is even a feasible task and what the right approach would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes this is something Django can do.

Fundamentally right now your application is just a client. You need a server to both:

A) use a database to store your data (whatever you currently store in local storage), and

B) share that data with your two clients

Django is a web framework designed to create such servers, so it's a great option.  However, Django also requires knowing Python.  If you don't know Python, and aren't learning it in a class, you may instead find it easier to use a different tool: Node.js

Node lets you use Javascript the same as other languages (eg. Python).  It also has frameworks (eg. instead of Django it has Express.js).  But again, if you don't mind Python, Django is a great choice.

Whatever your choice of framework, your first step will be to understand how it sets up "routes" or "endpoints" to talk to your client (you'll also have to learn how to have that client "talk" using `fetch` or `$.ajax`).

Once you master that, you can then learn to use a database to store the information you need, and finally you just "connect the dots" between those routes and your database to create your server.

I should warn you though that this is a sizable project, involving several complex technologies (servers, databases, AJAX, etc.)  I actually teach a college class on server-side development, so please understand I speak from experience when I say that ... even to make a simple server with a little bit of data ... you'll have to learn *a lot* (with Django or any other tool).